# Timer resetting after midnight

Tags: java, android, time, service, calendar

I've got a couple of users in my app reporting a weird behavior of a time reset/bug, i was baffled by it and after testing and collecting logs - i figured that my timer, if started before midnight, resets to 20+ hours instantly, i've can't figure out why or how to prevent this.

The project is open source and anyone is welcome to help me with this, here are the links:

[GitHub](https://github.com/Alikaraki95/Getoffyourphone)

Info about the app/project:

- Select apps, select desired lock-down time, lock apps.

[My Timer Class ( Full )](https://github.com/Alikaraki95/Getoffyourphone/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nephi/getoffyourphone/Timer_Service.java)

Time/Date related snippet

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:M:ss");

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    intent = new Intent(str_receiver);


    //DB
    db = new DB_Helper(this);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert alarmService != null;
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.e("Service_Auto_Restart", "ON");
}

public String twoDatesBetweenTime() {


    try {
        date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        date_diff = simpleDateFormat.parse(db.get_Data(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {


        long diff = date_current.getTime() - date_diff.getTime();
        int int_hours = Integer.valueOf(db.get_Hours(1));
        long int_timer;
        if (int_hours > 10) {
            int_timer = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(int_hours);
        } else {
            int_timer = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(int_hours);
        }
        long long_hours = int_timer - diff;
        long diffSeconds2 = long_hours / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes2 = long_hours / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours2 = long_hours / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;


        if (long_hours >= 0) {
            str_testing = String.format("%d:%d:%02d", diffHours2, diffMinutes2, diffSeconds2);
            Log.e("TIME", str_testing);
            db.set_TimerFinish(0);
            //db.set_Running("Y");
            fn_update(str_testing);
        } else {
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timer_Service.class));
            notification_update();
            db.set_TimerFinish(1);
            db.set_Running("N");
            //db.set_LockTime("");
            db.set_Hours("");
            db.set_Data("");
            //db.set_openCounter(0);
            db.set_openTimes(0);
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timer_Service.class));
        db.set_TimerFinish(1);
        db.set_Running("N");
        // db.set_LockTime("");
        db.set_Hours("");
        db.set_Data("");
        //db.set_openCounter(0);
        db.set_openTimes(0);
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer.purge();
    }

    return "";

}
```

Any suggestions ?

---

EDIT:

- Timer works fine, if someone sets the lockdown for example, 30 minutes, it will countdown 30 minutes and unlock when it's done.

Let's say someone started the lockdown at 21:30:00, timer will work just fine and end at 10:00:00.

However, if someone started the lockdown at 23:55:00 for 30 minutes, the "Time left to unlock" will jump to 21 hours, instead of 30 minutes. This only happens when a new day starts/timer starts before midnight.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")` to create the `DateFormat`? Uppercase `M` means "Month in year", and I believe it's also necessary to use two letters for hour and minute if you want them left-zero-padded (which you definitely do for the minutes, and you also do for the hours if using a 24hr clock).

Comment: @Bobulous Yes, i changed that for a specific user, and i found it better. That changes the 0 padding that displays.

Comment: But surely the capital `M` is incorrect? You surely want the lowercase `m` that means minutes?

Comment: @Bobulous capital M isn't affecting anything, the code works perfectly, been working for a long time. However the only issue here is the one i'm stating above about the time reset between days/after midnight.

Comment: Even if you cannot [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), could you at least give precise input, expected result and observed result for a case where the unwanted behaviour happens?

Comment: @OleV.V. Added a little example/use case at the end of the post - I will add screenshots and a video right now.

Comment: Thanks; your question already makes much more sense.